# Automatically write ViewModel changes back to config

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have written this Fiddle for a simple example of sharing data between multiple components that can all view and edit the data. (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ja6)

Using `publishes` and `reference` I am able to sync any changes to the components config values straight onto the components ViewModel. However I would like to also do the same the other way around, i.e. when this component's ViewModel changes have those values written back to the config.

In the fiddle I am achieving it by doing the following in initComponent:

```
this.getViewModel().bind('{pnform.firstName}', this.setFirstName, this);
this.getViewModel().bind('{pnform.lastName}', this.setLastName, this);
```

However I feel like there should be a way to remove this boiler plate code.  I thought that `twoWayBindable` sounded like it should do what I want, but it doesn't.

Do you know if there is a way to do this without having to write code like the above?

Comment: [This](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?285118-Two-Way-Data-Binding-Between-Two-Components) is a bit old, but may be what you are searching for. If I understand correctly, both components should use the same viewModel. In your fiddle, you have an inline definition of the view models in the views, so each view uses a different view model.